"It's both talent and hard work that are/is required." — Why is "are" incorrect? "Both talent and hard work" is plural and must agree only with "are"
proofreadnow.com:

If the subject consists of two or more words that are connected by "and" or by "both ... and", the subject is plural and requires a plural verb.

From this text, I'm drawing the following conclusion:
(1a) Both talent and hard work are required. — correct
(1b) Both talent and hard work is required. — incorrect

forum.wordreference.com:

(2a) It is both talent and hard work that are required. — This it-cleft sentence is incorrect because "it is" is a mismatch for plural "that are".
(2b) It is both talent and hard work that is required. — This it-cleft sentence is correct.

That is, when the sentence was ordinary, we used "are", but when we converted it into the it-cleft construction, the usage of "are" immediately became incorrect. This is perplexing me very much.
Why is "are" in (2a) incorrect?
Why is "is" in (2b) correct?

Maybe "both" is a magic word and if we remove it the rules will begin working the normal way:
(3a) It is talent and hard work that are required. — Is this correct now?
(3b) It is talent and hard work that is required. — And this is incorrect, right?

You have only the word of one poster on the Wordreference forum that 2b is correct, but I think I agree with them. "It" implies something like "the combination of qualities necessary" and so is singular.

Are these sentences from a chapter called How Clumsy Can We Make It?

@KateBunting You wrote: ""It" implies something like "the combination of qualities necessary"" — Does this mean you don't perceive "it" as a dummy pronoun? That is, you feel as if "it" must refer to some previous context with "the combination of qualities necessary" mentioned. Did I understand you correctly? Thanks.

Why would we ever convert it to an it-cleft? Most native speakers would intuit that an it-cleft is not the way to make things any clearer or more emphatic. What's required is both hard work and talent.

What @TimR said. The question is effectively pointless. Obviously there's scope for logical inconsistencies if you insist on using an it-cleft construction with multiple subjects (or subjects of "indeterminate" plurality). Native speakers routinely overlook inconsistencies in such contexts - but if it actually matters, just don't use the it-cleft construction. Don't waste time and effort trying to find the "correct" way to fit a square peg into a round hole.

Yes, of course it is a dummy pronoun - a singular pronoun representing plural subjects.

Cambridge Dictionary explains it-cleft sentences:

When a plural subject is the focus, we use a plural verb but It + be remains singular:
It’s the parents who were protesting most.

The OP's example

(2a) It is both talent and hard work that are required.

is correct.  Similarly,

(3a) It is talent and hard work that are required.

is correct.
The inclusion or otherwise of both does not play a part in determining the plurality of the verb in the relative clauses.

Both versions are correct grammar.
The version with "are" is correct because "talent and hard work" is a plural subject. IMO, it's also the much more natural version.
The version with "is" is also correct. Because it's in the singular, it refers to the combination of "talent and hard work" as a single item. It's obviously two concepts, but the grammar allows it.
Take these reworded versions:

(1c) The key is both talent and hard work.
(2c) It is both talent and hard work that's the key.

Here, I hope it's somewhat clearer that "talent and hard work" can be considered a single element by the speaker, and if so, "is" is correct.
NOTE: Cleft sentences are almost always clunky and awkward, as is the case here, and compounded by the singular verb after a plural-looking subject. There's always a more natural way to rephrase. This cleft structure is mostly used to sacrifice style for clarity when the natural phrasing is ambiguous, has negative connotations, etc..

The number of the verb changes because you have changed the number of the subject.
"Both talent and hard work are required." The subject is "both talent and hard work". That is a plural. It's clearly two things: talent AND hard work. So the verb must be plural.
"It is both talent and hard work that is required." The subject is "It". That is a singular, so the verb must be singular.
Yes, the writer explains that "it" includes two things: talent and hard work. But GRAMMATICALLY, "it" is still singular. The construction "it is" is often followed by a plural. "It is Bob and Mary who will go." Even though two people will go, the subject is "it", which is singular, so I say "It is ...", NOT "It are ..."
"It" in such constructions is not referring to the list that follows but to the state of being.

The question is not about "It is/are ...". It's about "It is ... that is/are ...". Your example without "will" proves that the verb after "who" must be in plural: "It is Bob and Mary who go there every morning.", NOT "who goes". Then why must there be "that is" (in singular) in my example whereas "who go" (in plural) in yours?
